# Equidistributed Sequences and Riemann-Integrability

Tags: riemann-integration, equidistribution

Recently I have been researching about equidistributed sequences. In the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence, I found the next theorem:

> The sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is equidistributed on $[a,b]$ if and only if for every Riemann-integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ , the following limit holds: $$\lim\limits _{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits _{n=1}^{N}f(s_{n})=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{ d}x$$

(In the original version $f$ is complex-valued, but this version is very easily verified as true as well).

Furthermore, in the same Wikipedia page it says:

> **de Bruijn–Post Theorem** states the converse of the above criterion: If $f$ is a function such that the criterion above holds for any equidistributed sequence in $[a,b]$, then $f$ is Riemann-integrable in $[a,b]$.

I was not successful in finding any proof for that last theorem, not by myself nor online. My questions are:

1. Can you present a proof of *de Bruijn–Post Theorem*, or maybe give me a link to a useful resource?
2. Would it be possible to redefine Riemann-integrable function as one that satisfies that criterion, and then to construct the entire theory from this direction?

Comment: The French Wikipedia had an archive of the related document referenced for that theorem, document which otherwise didn't seem to exist anymore in the French and English pages alike: https://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/index2.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.uga.edu%2F%7Epete%2Fudnotes.pdf%2Findex.html#federation=archive.wikiwix.com&tab=url

Comment: Theorem $8$ is what you want in that paper.

Comment: @BrunoB: the paper seems available on Pete Clark page http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/udnotes.pdf

Comment: Thank you both very much :)